# telnet connects, but mysql times out

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2016, remote-access

I have access to two servers:

- `A` runs Ubuntu Server and I connect to it via SSH
- `B` runs Windows Server 10

`A` should be able to connect to `B:1433` to the MySQL Server.

Both `A` and `B` are on the same network.

I have tried to do:

```
mycli --verbose -u USER -h IP_OF_SERVER_B -P 1433 -p '...'
```

This times out.

However, `nmap` shows the 1433 port as open and `telnet` can connect to it.

```
$ sudo nmap IP_OF_SERVER_B
[sudo] password for ...: 

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-07-23 04:45 UTC
Nmap scan report for IP_OF_SERVER_B
Host is up (0.0014s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1433/tcp open  ms-sql-s
```

And:

```
$ telnet IP_OF_SERVER_B 1433
Trying IP_OF_SERVER_B...
Connected to 10.10.1.7.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

How can I connect to the MySQL Server? I already enabled remote access on the MySQL Server side.

Comment: 1433 is the default port of Microsoft SQL Server. You can connect via [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is running MS SQL, and you are trying to connect to it using MySQL client.

MySQL and MS SQL are different products, and you cannot use tools designed for MySQL to access MS SQL server.

You need to use MS SQL client to access your MS SQL server.

Comment: Thanks for this. I followed the instructions and installed `sqlcmd`. But now the error I get is `SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available` and `Cannot generate SSPI context.`. I tried `sqlcmd -S IP_OF_SERVER_B`.

Comment: You need to check how your server's authentication is set up and adjust accordingly.